# Maven - Auto Respond 'yes' on all user input

Tags: java, maven

Currently I have a grails/maven project. Right now I'm upgrading my grails proj to 1.2.1. The problem is that the upgrade asks for user input, and if I my CI server tries to build it, it will stall asking the user if he wants to upgrade certain plugins.

Is there a way to tell maven to respond 'y' on all user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that `grails upgrade` target has a `'--non-interactive`' option that disables user input. It was just a matter of wiring this with my CI server.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the --batch-mode option.  This is supposed to automatically answer questions with "sensible" default answers ... whatever that means.

Failing that, on UNIX / LINUX you could try `yes | mvn <options> ...`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't knew about the --batch-mode